# Converting a method to a generic method

Tags: java, generics, playing-cards

I am writing a texas holdem game and created this method to rank the user hand I want to turn it into a generic method so I can pass the dealer hand and then compare the two to see which hand will be better. If you could please help me with converting this into a generic method I would appreciate it.

```
public int rankCards(ArrayList<Integer> rankHandList){
    //creates a list to put the card ranks into 
    ArrayList <Integer> newList;
    newList = new ArrayList<>();
    //Checks the rankHandList i created above
    for(int x = 0; x<=rankHandList.size()-1; x++){
        int rank = rankHandList.get(x);
        //takes all the cards and gets them between 0 and 12
        while(rank >= 13){
            rank = rank -13;
        }
        //if a card = 12 it is an ace
        if(rank == 12)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 11 it is a king
        if(rank == 11)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 10 it is a queen
        if(rank == 10)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 9 it is a jack
        if(rank == 9)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 8 it is a 10
        if(rank == 8)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 7 it is a 9
        if(rank ==7)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 6 it is a 8
        if(rank ==6)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 5 it is a 7
        if(rank ==5)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 4 it is a 6
        if(rank ==4)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 3 it is a 5
        if(rank ==3)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 2 it is a 4
        if(rank == 2)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card =1 it is a 3
        if(rank ==1)
            newList.add(rank);
        //if a card = 0 it is a 2
        if(rank ==0)
            newList.add(rank);
    }

  //SENDS THE CARDS I JUST RANKED FROM 0-12 TO MAKE THE BEST HAND   
    makeBestHand(newList);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What help do you want specifically? What have you tried? How is it not working? Please improve this question if you can as right now it looks like a homework dump, which I'm sure is not your intent.

Comment: Instead of creating the same exact method for the dealer hand I want to be able to pass the dealer ArrayList and have it run through this method. I have tried changing the types to T and so forth but nothing I do seams to work. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to do math with Integers pretty much you need to know they are Integers first so you have to pass an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Your question doesn't really explain why you think generics will help you out here. I can't tell what you actually want to do. Plus it seems like you haven't really tried anything yet.

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive enough. I did solve my problem myself. I was just over thinking what I needed to do. All I needed to do was change rankHandList to T. Simple enough. Thanks all for trying to help with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understood what you wanted, for what i understood you wanted to re-factored your code.

```
public int rankCards(ArrayList<Integer> rankHandList) {
    // Creates a list to put the card ranks into 
    ArrayList <Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Checks the rankHandList i created above
    for (int rank : rankHandList) {
        // Add card rank into the list, after module 13 to normalize rank.
        newList.add(rank%13);
    }

    //SENDS THE CARDS I JUST RANKED FROM 0-12 TO MAKE THE BEST HAND   
    makeBestHand(newList);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Orel Eraki for helping me simplify my code. I changed my giant if statement to what you suggested and it works great.